# I want to add a simpe formula in VBA but I dont know how to execute it (IF/ELSE)

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am very much new to this but would like to have my excel life simple.
I could not find online what I exactly want, and all those AI-excel things are tedious, or they want money.
Hopefully you can help me.

I want in excel. If cell C26 contain YES then cells D26 and E26 are empty (and can be adjustable by writing own text). If cell C26 contains NO, then write in cells D26 and E26 "N/A".
The yes and no are chosen from a drop down list.

Thank you in advance :)

I tried using:

```
=IF(EXACT(C26,"No"),"N/A","")
```

But maybe I forgot something or don't understand how VBA works.

[rough snip of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0KhZ.png)

Comment: *dont understand how VBA works* It's not the same using formulas in Excel (that would be kind of *pure* Excel) than using VBA (a coding language with their own rules). Try this: Go to cell D26 and inside type `=IF(C26="YES","","N/A")` and see if that is what you mean.

Comment: If the formula is in the cell in excel itself it works, but I want to be able to write text in the cell that the formula is, that's why I want to switch to VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Worksheet_Change` event handler:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C26")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Select Case Me.Range("C26").Value
        Case "YES", vbNullString
            Me.Range("D26:E26").ClearContents
        Case "NO"
            Me.Range("D26:E26").Value = "N/A"
    End Select
End Sub
```

If you don't want anything to happen when C26 = "YES", then remove the "YES" from:

```
Case "YES", vbNullString
```

---

EDIT: For a multiple cell setup:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C26:C27")) ' Change C26:C27 as needed

    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell in rng
        Select Case cell.Value
            Case "YES", vbNullString
                 cell.Offset(,1).Resize(,3).ClearContents
            Case "NO"
                 cell.Offset(,1).Resize(,3).Value = "N/A"
        End Select
    Next

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: A quick comment on where to put the code - right-click the tab name that contains your ranges and select **View Code**.  Paste it in there.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!!
Just a small question, is there a way to have N/A written there and not #N/A?
And if I wanted to add more like this with other cells, can I combine this in the formula or add separate ones?

Comment: Oh sorry.  See the edit for N/A. Yes you can add more cells to this.

Comment: Can I bother you with 2 more questions?
How to add if you remove the YES or NO, the cells will return to former state and not contain the N/A?

And is there a line that I have to put in between the formulas if I want the same text but for different cells?

Comment: Edited to address the first issue. For the second issue, sounds like you want to change the `D26:E26`? What specifically do you mean by "different cells"?

Comment: I added a quick picture above. I have C26 where I have to choose YES or NO from a dropdown list. If YES then the cells D26:F26 have to stay empty. If I choose NO D26:F26 have to contain N/A. This would be the same for the row beneath too. If C27 is YES then D27:F27 have to stay empty and if NO then D27:F27 have to contain N/A.
But if I press NO by accident, and delete it or choose blank, I want it to remove the N/A automatically instead that I have to press delete.